# How do I fix my table from breaking my css div? PHP LOOP

Tags: php, css, html, while-loop

I have a header div, content div, and a footer div, and my content is a PHP loop returning results from my database, but my results are under my footer div, and my footer div is up over my content div?

I need help please.

HTML/PHP:
http://pastebin.com/88mVStFf

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/r22jvVbn

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You get a big hairy downvote for not bothering with this question at all. You need to post a small, relevant snippet of your HTML, PHP and CSS _in the question_

Comment: How can you post a small snippet of the code if you have no idea whats wrong? In this case I think his effort with the pastebins is worth an upvote and not a downvote. Its not like its all garbled code and like 1000 lines or so.

Comment: As an addon on Bojangles's comment, you can try to follow the guidelines on [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) next time ;)

Comment: @HugoDelsing, as documented on SSCCE you can start removing small pieces of code to identify whether or not the problem persists. However this would have taken way more time in this case, since the solution was rather obvious.

Comment: Well, I'm relevantly new to stackoverflow and I only post when I'm stuck on something I'm currently working on to get done. I'll try to pste little parts next time, but I agree with @HUGO DELSING

Comment: Just a tip for next time ;) A SSCCE also helps other future readers to understand the real issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are not closing your table (`</table>`) on line 118 of your HTML/PHP Pastebin.

Also a sidenote, you can make a header for a table by using `<th></th>` instead of `<tr></tr>`.

Comment: OMG, thank you lol. I knew it had to be something simple. I overlooked it.

Comment: select this as the answer to your question, if it helped you entirely with the problem